# Checking for Duplicates Using For-In Loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-in-loop

I'm doing a codewars challenge that checks if Sudoku grid is valid.

https://www.codewars.com/kata/529bf0e9bdf7657179000008/train/javascript

It returns false if there are duplicate values in 1) horizontal line, 2) vertical line, 3) 3x3 block, and 4) incomplete (if there are 0s). I'm stuck on checking the horizontal line.

I am using the `values` array to store the numbers then using the `for in` loop to check if it's a duplicate. If it is, return false. The problem in the code is checking the first horizontal line `[5, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2]`. It returns `false` when checking `1` and I don't know why.

```
function validSolution(board) {
  let valid = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

  // testing for 0's
  for (let i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
      if (board[i][j] === 0) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }

  // testing horizontal line
  for (let i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
    values = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
      console.log(values);
      console.log(board[i][j]);
      if (board[i][j] in values) { // problem is here once the value reaches 1 on the first horizontal line.
        console.log(board[i][j]); 
        return false;
      } else {
        values.push(board[i][j]);
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
}

console.log( // this array is a valid board and should return true.
  validSolution([
    [5, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2],
    [6, 7, 2, 1, 9, 5, 3, 4, 8],
    [1, 9, 8, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6, 7],
    [8, 5, 9, 7, 6, 1, 4, 2, 3],
    [4, 2, 6, 8, 5, 3, 7, 9, 1],
    [7, 1, 3, 9, 2, 4, 8, 5, 6],
    [9, 6, 1, 5, 3, 7, 2, 8, 4],
    [2, 8, 7, 4, 1, 9, 6, 3, 5],
    [3, 4, 5, 2, 8, 6, 1, 7, 9],
  ])
);
```

I'm console logging both the element in the index and the value. Here is the result:

```
(0) []
5
(1) [5]
3
(2) [5, 3]
4
(3) [5, 3, 4]
6
(4) [5, 3, 4, 6]
7
(5) [5, 3, 4, 6, 7]
8
(6) [5, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8]
9
(7) [5, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]
1
1
false
```

Comment: values is an empty array, also, it miss a declaration

Comment: `x in y` returns true if a property named x is present in the object y.  You are trying to see if an element exists in an array.  For that, you can try `if (values.includes(board[i][j]))`

Comment: Is it a stupid question to ask why it works for the other digits except for 1? Or is it undefined just because I'm using a function designed for an object on an array.

Answer (score 0):

I think Boolean algebra should not be underestimated

```js
function check1to9valid( arrN )
  {
  let binVal = 0;
  for (let v of arrN)
    {
    let bin = 2 ** v // Number(v)
    if (binVal & bin)  { binVal = 0; break; } // avoid duplicates
    else               { binVal |= bin;     }
    }
  return (binVal === 0b1111111110 ) 
  }


const validGrid =
  [ [ 5, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2 ]
  , [ 6, 7, 2, 1, 9, 5, 3, 4, 8 ]
  , [ 1, 9, 8, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6, 7 ]
  , [ 8, 5, 9, 7, 6, 1, 4, 2, 3 ]
  , [ 4, 2, 6, 8, 5, 3, 7, 9, 1 ]
  , [ 7, 1, 3, 9, 2, 4, 8, 5, 6 ]
  , [ 9, 6, 1, 5, 3, 7, 2, 8, 4 ]
  , [ 2, 8, 7, 4, 1, 9, 6, 3, 5 ]
  , [ 3, 4, 5, 2, 8, 6, 1, 7, 9 ]
  ]

let isValid = true

// testing horizontal lines
for (let arrLine of validGrid )
  {
  if (!check1to9valid( arrLine )) 
    {
    isValid = false;
    break;
    }
  }

console.log('all grid\'s lines are valid :', isValid )

// testing vertical lines
isValid = true

for (let i=0; i< 9; i++ )
  {
  if (!check1to9valid( validGrid.map(line=>line[i]) )) 
    {
    isValid = false;
    break;
    }
  }

console.log('all grid\'s columns are valid : ', isValid )
```